# Pronunciation and meaning of 

Tags: meaning, pronunciation, katakana

I just received an email ending like this:

> 是非是非また誘って

How to read the `` ?
Zero results on Google.

As for the meaning, is it equivalent to `よ` ?

Comment: you mean ~ <- this? I'm not sure what you are talking about, but if that's it, then it's like friendly please. よ is more less friendly but still friendly.

Comment: is that a little square?

Comment: @wallyqs: No, no little squares.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's [*mojibake*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), not a valid character. Looking at the character code I suppose it's this *emoji* sent from a mobile phone:

[image: emoji]

http://code.iamcal.com/php/emoji/

Comment: oh crap, that php library is awesome. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 14):

The character you presented is U+E4FB. According to the Unicode standard, it is in the "private use area", which means a software or hardware vendor can define what the character means on their own system. Such a character has no universally accepted meaning.

Reference: [Wikipedia - Mapping of Unicode characters - Private use characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters#Private_use_characters)

"*The Basic Multilingual Plane includes a PUA in the range from U+E000 to U+F8FF (6,400).*"

Comment: How are you guys reading the code points?

Comment: @Louis: http://i.imgur.com/HkcMA.png

Comment: @Ignacio, ohh, they are empty boxes on my version of Chrome.

Comment: If you're a programmer, you can use JavaScript to figure out the code point, i.e. by typing this into the address bar: `javascript: "X".charCodeAt(0).toString(16)`